# Website is not loading properly on https

Tags: css, angular

My website was working perfect since it was running on http. After migrating it to https , some of the css is not reflecting properly. I've checked many things like 304 error , done versioning of css files , transferred all requests to https instead of http. This is the link :- https://stratgist.com. Please check tell me the solution to this

Comment: its working fine here

Comment: Try reloading it several times and also tell me your browser

Comment: have you migrated all unsafe links i.e. in http to https? i.e. all instances of http reference in your site?

Comment: @SriramJayaraman yes all of them

Answer (score 3):

Site is working fine to me, Just some js and css files are not loading and console showing it.

It might have cache of your browser. Open browser and do <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f5</kbd> or else open site in Incognito mode/private window of your browser.

Comment: Tried all of these things , it's not a cache problem. Sometimes it works fine , sometimes not. It works perfectly on mobile browsers

Comment: @HarkamalSingh Not sure why it is not working for you, Here I didn't see any issue with site loading, It working perfectly with me, Tried refreshing as well as tried on multiple PC's in my home :(

Comment: Are you facing this issue on Home page or on any specific page ?

Comment: All pages , basically in slider and menu bar

Comment: raVan96 . Can you mention the screen metrics and your browser?

Comment: @HarkamalSingh I am using Version 65.0.3325.181 (Official Build) (64-bit) of chrome.